# Does not show Full screen pager in android

Tags: android

How can i get the pager view as a full screen in android?
Please help.I already have a pager but it is not extending to full size.Its width is being covered, but not the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your manifest on your activity which you want to show full screen

```
<activity
    android:name="com.your_package.YourActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
</activity>
```

Comment: I want the title bar but it should cover up the entire screen

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.FullScreen" try that instead of above

Comment: I wanted the full activity screen with TITLE BAR

Comment: So, you should change width and height of your activity's layout to fill_parent

Answer (score 0):

Are you using match_parent for layout_height and layout_width?

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 android:id="@+id/viewpager"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```